# Find the node responsible to run the Quartz job

Tags: cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, interrupt, job-scheduling

I am using Quartz 1.8.5 . My Application is deployed in cluster environment.
I need to stop the currently running job what I can do by following.

```
stdScheduler.interrupt(jobName,jobGroupName);
```

But, I don't know which node is responsible to run this job.
Could someone please suggest, during execution of this job how can I get the node information.

Comment: Which application server hosts your application?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `System.getProperty("weblogic.Name")` you can get the node name.

Comment: Thanks  and sorry for my delayed reply. 
But I want to know does quartz api provides this information during Job execution. 
As DB table fired_triggers keeps this information in column  “INSTANCE_NAME” after execution of this job.
But I need this information when job is running.